# how to match the exact value contained in one string to the other string

Tags: java, string, iterator, match

I have two database tables .first table contains 'Destination' column which has destination phone numbers and second table contains 'Areacode' which has the areacodes.

Suppose : Destination number='001891191080'
          Areacode :001,0018,00185 etc

Now the problem is this that the destination number is matching 001 Areacode instead of 0018..

```
 for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
        try {
            String ss = destination.substring(0, i);
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asteriskcdrdb", "root", "techsoft");
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from sp1 where areacode like '" + ss + "'");
            while (rs.next()) {
                areacode = rs.getString("AreaCode");
```

Here Sir as per my need i am taking the destination value and checking with for loop starting from the last .but as soon as it matches the first value it skips and doesnot check other and exact possibility...
How to match the exact values out of so many possibilities ...
Any help will be highly appreciated..
Thanx in advance

Comment: @subodh Sir i posted my code and logic

Comment: @Aswathi Sir i posted my codes

Comment: My SQL is a little rusty, but couldn't you use `like '" + ss + "%'` instead?

Comment: Creating Connection object inside For loop is not a good practice. You can make Class.forName(), and getConnection() call before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
Destination number='001891191080' Areacode :001,0018
```

By using `String#subString(begin index,End index)` you can make short string and try to match both .

you should not create connection and statement` in a for loop.

Comment: Sir i tried the same thing in my codes .just now i posted my codes plz check it sir.

Answer (score 0):

First sort the 'Areacode' based on length of string (more to less), then check for the match in 'destination number'.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the big string match first e.g.

```
   String destNumber = "001891191080";
   String[] areaCodes = new String[]{ "001","0018"};

   if(destNumber.indexOf(areaCodes[1])>=0){   //<- use 0018 first
     //....
   }else if(destNumber.indexOf(areaCodes[0])>=0){
     //...
   }
```

Comment: Negative Voter: Please add some comment to help me understand the gap/issue.

Comment: @Adarsh Can you please share the code you wrote(I don't see relevant code in your question) and what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this query?

```
"Select * from sp1 where areacode like '" + ss + "%' order by areacode desc"
```

So that should give you

```
00185
0018
001
```

in the resultset and the comparison would return you the first value from the list.

Comment: Thank you Sir..but it would match starting values with the araecode and once it get that value in araecode it will skip finding the exact one and will take that one

Comment: Does that mean u have an exact value to be matched to?

Comment: So that means you have an expected value to be matched against the resultset strings. If so, it's so simple to write an if condition right?